# How to display image result processing in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, web

So, I had an image grayscale I uploading on my web(I've done it), and I want to return show the result (mask from my model). How can I show it up on my flask web app?

I've tried my self and the result still like this:
[image]

which is, the result (mask) image not show up, but saved on my upload file not returning on the web.

and here is my coding for uploading the image:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the file from post request
        f = request.files['file']

        # Save the file to ./uploads
        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        file_path = os.path.join(
            basepath, 'uploads', secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(file_path)

        # Make prediction
        preds = model_predict(file_path, model)
        imageio.imwrite(file_path.replace('_z_','_z_mask_'), np.uint8(preds*255)[0, :, :, 0])

        # Process your result for human
        # pred_class = preds.argmax(axis=-1)            # Simple argmax
        #pred_class = decode_predictions(preds, top=1)   # ImageNet Decode
        #result = str(pred_class[0][0][1])               # Convert to string
        result = ""
        return result
    return None
```

and here is my code on `html` for the result:

```
<div class="image-section" style="display:none;">
    <div class="img-preview">
        <div id="imagePreview">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " id="btn-predict">Predict!</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="loader" style="display:none;"></div>

<h3 id="result">
    <span><img src="{{ user_image }}" alt="User Image"> </span>
</h3>
```

Comment: Ok so you want to take image, return mask of it to html and show it on the page. Am I right? Because I didn't completely understand your question

Comment: @charchit yes, that's it, sorry if my question not easy to understand.

Comment: what the user_image variable equal to in html. If you want to display grayscale then you can save the files in static folder and then use `{{url_for('static',filename='name_of_saved_image')}}`

Comment: @charchit so, it works out if I save it in a static folder?

Comment: Yes only [static](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://python-adv-web-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flask3.html&ved=2ahUKEwiogujsvZLxAhVT4zgGHeDsBFoQFjABegQIBBAF&usg=AOvVaw0XD2frwAgogA4xJ_SPK2HC&cshid=1623514250067) folder, in root directory of your project

Comment: @charcit I've tried the answer from you, but it seems still cannot show up the image below the result when I process to predict the mask from my MRI image. what if the image more than one? how to automatically show another mask? and the code from you is like this right? `<h3 id="result">
        <span><img src="{{url_for('static',filename='image/sol_032_z_mask_pos_008_t_pos_007.png')}}"> </span>
    </h3>`

Comment: If you want to show more than one image then you can use os module to list the contents of static folder, pass it to html and then use a for loop in jinja 2 show all the images in the folder

Comment: ah i seee thanks @charchit